# GCM webpush in background

Tags: chrome-gcm, web-push, push-api

I implemented web push notifications. Steps to get a bug:

1. Open website
2. Subscribe for push notifications
3. Send many pushes through gcm - all fine
4. Close tab with site
5. Send push and receive "double push" - first one is ok, second is "This site has been updated in background"
6. Reopen website
7. Send push - all fine

I know this can happen when the service worker receives push and doesn't show notification. But I see normal notification, why I also see other strange notification? Can I get rid such behaviour?

Comment: Can you clarify #5? Are you sending one push message but receiving two of them? Or just sending two push messages?

Comment: Also is this on desktop or Android?

Comment: @MiguelGarcia I tested it on desktop. #5 Sending one push message - receave two pushes. First is real, second is not.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I am returning a promise all the time. Maybe you can help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948633/how-to-prevent-chrome-background-notifications-from-showing-twice-when-adding-we

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  // this function should return promise always
}
```

In my case:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription()
      .then(function(subscription) {
        fetch('url')
          .then(function(response) {
            self.registration.showNotification('title', {});
          });
      });
  );
}
```

should be:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription()
      .then(function(subscription) {
        return fetch('url')
          .then(function(response) {
            return self.registration.showNotification('title', {});
          });
      });
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had this same issue, and was missing the return statement before the fetch call.

Comment: That "answer" is poorly formatted. The questions: 1.) Why am I seeing strange notifications? **UNANSWERED** 2.) Can I get rid of such behavior? (How do I is implied) You have some code, but no indication of where it's from, how to get to it, what needs to be changed, how you found it, or even confirming that this *will* "get rid of such behavior". Please update the answer with the appropriate information.