# Error Message while receiving GCM

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

When my service worker invokes a secured API that returns content, I do receive an error message, such that The Site has been updated in background. Can anyone please help me out ?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [link](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/issues/60), the message `This site has been updated in the background` is a forced message from the Chrome browser when the SDK cannot fetch the notification contents to retrieve. Notification contents are not sent to our background worker; instead we receive a signal to display a notification and then we fetch the notification contents from our server.

> This behavior is most likely triggered by the user having multiple notifications pings, but only one message to receive.

You may also check this related SO post: [Chrome Push Notification: This site has been updated in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108699/chrome-push-notification-this-site-has-been-updated-in-the-background)

> Generally as soon as you receive a push message from GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) you have to show a push notification in the browser. This is mentioned on the 3rd point in here:
>
> https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web#what-are-the-limitations-of-push-messaging-in-chrome-42
>
> So it might happen that somehow you are skipping the push notification though you got a push message from GCM and you are getting a push notification with some default message like "This site has been updated in the background".

Hope this helps!