# Cancel sent Web Push notifications

Tags: progressive-web-apps, web-push, web-notifications

I'm sending push notifications to my website users when they (for example) receive a private message.
That notification goes to all browsers subscribed for that user. So could be desktop, mobile, work computer etc.

What I would like to do is close all the sent notifications once the user has a read a message.

So user logs in on mobile, reads the private message - at this point I want all the previously sent notifications for that PM to be closed/cancelled.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!
Matt

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Mr Rebot.
I don't need help debugging code.  I just need to know if there's any way to cancel (remotely close) web push notifications that I've already sent out.  I have no code for it - I need to know if that even exists or is possible with the web push API.  I cannot find anything about it online

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, but not silently. For example, Chrome will replace the notification with a new one saying "This site has been updated in the background".

There are two separate APIs: the [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API) which "gives web applications the ability to receive messages pushed to them from a server", and the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) which "is used to configure and display desktop notifications to the user".

The Notification API provides [`Notification.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/close), which cancels the display of a notification.

You can use the Push API to trigger `Notification.close()`. Here's a sample which should go in your service worker:

```js
self.addEventListener('push', async event => {
  const data = event.data.json();
  if (data.type === 'display_notification') {
    self.registration.showNotification(data.title, data.options);
  } else if (data.type === 'cancel_notification') {
    const notifications = await self.registration.getNotifications({
      tag: data.notificationTag
    });
    for (notification of notifications) {
      notification.close();
    }
  } else {
    console.warn("Unknown message type", event, data);
  }
});
```

However! This design means that your `cancel_notification` message won't display a notification. This violates some browser policies, for example [Chrome will display a new notification saying "This site has been updated in the background"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31181089/229792).